# regular expression get number from string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, scrapy

#### First I am using python 2.7

I have these possibilities of the string:

```
3 paths

12  paths

12 path rooms
```

#### Question

what is the reqular expression to get the number without the text.

#### thanks

Comment: Why not just split on the space? Or - do you have other examples that means that's not viable...

Comment: @JonClements since I am using scrapy, i am allowed to use just xpath and reqular expression, i can't use python functions

Comment: errr no... once you've extracted the string, there's nothing to stop you using builtin `str` operations

Comment: @JonClements I do know that :). I mean that in the policy of where I am working I can't use python functions

Comment: okay... I've put the scrapy tag back - you might want to [edit] your question to include these comments and the fact that this is not a standalone regular expression with standalone strings...

Comment: @JonClements what did you mean please by saying `not a standalone regular expression with standalone strings` ?

Comment: Well, if you're not allowed to use Python functions, then you can't use the `re` module... therefore, given your own constraints, the only way is to use scrapy's `select(...).re(...)` style...? Otherwise, you could just use `str.split` to start with :)

Comment: I'm confused.  Why would you be allowed to use python but not python functions?

Comment: @limasxgoesto0 i am allowed to use just scrapy not the whole python

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, I understand that, but the restriction sounds extremely odd.  Is it for Python3 compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you can only use scrapy methods, so I guess you're after:

```
hxs.select('//some/xpath/expression/text()').re(r'(\d+).*')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:
Regex = [\d]*

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way would be to use [0-9] instead of \d

```
import re

def extract_number(string):
    r = re.compile('[0-9]+')
    return r.match(string).group()
```

Answer (score 1):

`(\d+).*\n` for pulling the numbers and then skipping the rest of the line.

`number_finder = re.compile('(\d+).*\n')
number_finder.findall(mystr)`

will output an array of the number values

Example:

`In [3]: r = re.compile('(\d+).*\n')
In [4]: r.findall('12 a \n 12 a \n')
Out[4]: ['12', '12']`

Comment: cross multiple-line search, just use `re.M` flag, it codes like `re.findall(r'\d+',multiple_line_string,re.M)` :-)

Answer (score 1):

The regex pattern to look for is `\d`. So in python you would code it as:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
result =  re.search(pattern, input_string)
```

Comment: you need to write `[\d]*` with the `*` so it will catch all the number and not just the first digit.

Comment: @ifryed You are right. We could alternatively do a `\d+`