# Get numbers from a string with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that could look like this:

`"Lesson 2.3"`

or this:

`"Lesson 12.5"`

Is there any way I can just *grab* the `2.3` or `12.5` or any other number with the same format from this string?  I'm not trying to turn it into a double or float, I just want the *string* part that has the numbers in it, i.e. "2.3" or "12.5".

I've tried using RegEx, but my attempt is only returning the first number:

`var number = Regex.Match(lessonTopicName, "\\d+").Value; // returns "2"`

I don't have a complete understanding of RegEx, so I know I'm doing this wrong.  I'd like to write a method where I can just pass in the string and it returns the numbers from the string in string format, if that makes sense.

Comment: A full number-matching regexp is a bit more than you need, so perhaps you could use `"\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)"` or similar...

Comment: If you want to keep it just as simple, make a character class with `\d` and `.`: `[\\d.]+`. Let me know if this is good enough for you and I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Looks like there was a answer already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232618/regular-expression-get-number-from-string

Comment: If it's always the word Lesson followed by a space and a number then use `string.Split` instead of Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d+` matches digits only. You need to match the period as well:

```
var number = Regex.Match(lessonTopicName, "\\d+\\.?\\d*").Value;
```

The period and following digits is made optional here by `?` (0 or 1) and `*` (0 or more). If you need to require a period and a decimal after it, that version would be:

```
var number = Regex.Match(lessonTopicName, "\\d+\\.\\d+").Value;
```

Comment: You should change the trailing `\\d+` to `\\d*` so it will match `"Lesson 1"`.

Comment: This worked just like I needed.  Ugh, I need to brush up on RegEx, it seems so useful in situations like this.  Thank you so much for your help.  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the timer is up.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var number = Regex.Match(lessonTopicName, "[0-9]+.[0-9]$").Value;
```

Comment: Maybe. I was just going with the examples given.

Comment: Hogwash. In fact, it is very similar to other answers posted here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = Regex.Match(lessonTopicName, @"\d+.\d+").Value;
```